# Magento 2: News letter Subscription for the products

Tags: magento2, product, newsletter-subscriber

How to send the email to Newsletter subscription users for every product updates, Discounts and offer details.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can create Newsletter Template from the Marketing section in admin and set "Queue Newsletter".
Please check detailed information about sending the newsletter,
https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/newsletter-queue.html

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below steps to create a newsletter template from Magento

- On the Admin Panel, Marketing > Communications > Newsletter Template.
- Click on the Add New Template, go to the workplace.
- Set Template Name for the new newsletter template
- Enter Template Subject to define what the newsletter is for.
- Insert the Sender Name who sends the newsletter to the subscribers.
- Insert the Sender Email that is the email address the newsletter is sent from.
- Click on the Show/Hide Editor button at the top of Template Content
  field to enable the WYSIWYG editor. It is flexible to edit and update
  the content as needed.
- After saving the template, you will be redirected to Newsletter
  Templates Page, select Queue Newsletter.
- Here you can set the date and time for sending out the newsletter.

**Hope it helps!!!**